# Update data in the database when to OK on alert

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a column in phpMyAdmin id call that gets integer values 1 or 0. When 1, the user enter the site an alert is displayed ('Welcome!'); how to do so that when the user clicks OK to be updated msg to 0?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");

    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var msg = event.data;
        if (msg>0){     
        alert('Welcome');
        };
    };
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**demo_sse.php**

```
<?php

$dominio = "127.0.0.1";
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "teste";
$codificacao = 'utf8';

$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

$sql= "select * from `msg`";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$tabela = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
$id=$tabela['id'];


header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data:{$id}\n\n";
flush();

?>
```

Comment: You should clarify what your question is and provide some code illustrating what it is you are trying to do and where you are having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a php script that switches that record to 0 then use the event of clicking the ok button to fire an Ajax request to that script.  The Ajax will run your php and give the effect you want.   If you need more instruction I can do a detailed example when I get to a computer.

Comment: Got it! Would you show me an example? For I am still new to Ajax